# Morphological erosion and dilation operation in latex

Tags: equations, symbols

Please help me writing the equation of morphological erosion and dilation operation in latex. I know how to write some part of it, but couldn't complete the whole equation.

[image: Morphological dilation operation]

[image: Morphological erosion operation]

I came up with these two codes so far.

```
\begin{equation}
    A \oplus b = {z|[(B^\string^)_z \cap A] \subseteq A}
\end{equation}
```

Here the problem is the "^" sign gets to the side of the character "B" instead of directly over it. Also the curly braces are not showing in output. I need them as it represents set.

```
\begin{equation}
    I \ominus b = {z| (B)_z \subseteq A and A \subseteq I} \cup {A^c| A^c \subseteq I}
\end{equation}
```

Here, also the curly braces are missing in output.

Comment: As this is not a `please do this for me` service, please show what you got so far. Note there is not reason at all to scale the `{}|` in these two equations.

Comment: You want `\hat{B}`; but you should check the definitions, because the first set, as defined from the formula, is the universal set. The two sets in the second formula have objects of different type.

Comment: @egreg The two definitions are different as the definition of A and I are different. here A is a set of foreground pixels, B is a structuring element.  I is a rectangular array of foreground and background pixels.

Comment: To get left or right braces _right_, instead of `{...}`, you can use `\left\{ ... \right\}` or `\big\{ ... \big\}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation and help from comments by @egreg and @Partha D, I came up with these solutions that worked for me.

```
\begin{equation}
    A \oplus B = \{z|[(\hat{B})_z \cap A] \subseteq A\}
\end{equation}
```

```
\begin{equation}
    I \ominus B = \{z| (B)_z \subseteq A \quad \textrm{and} \quad A \subseteq I\} \cup \{A^c| A^c \subseteq I\}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Good summarization.  However a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe) (both in the question and answer) is expected-- as the packages used do matter in the final result.